# How do I get rid of the extra padding around this custom widget? (flutter-dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a custom widget that is just a row of buttons.  However it is adding padding around the  buttons that I would like to remove, thing is I can't figure out how.

Here is what it looks like.

[image]

Here is the code for the individual button.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    onPressed: onPressed ?? null,
    color: color,
    textColor: iconColor,
    child: SvgPicture.asset(iconLocation,
        width: height / 2, height: height / 2, color: iconColor),
    shape: CircleBorder(),
    height: height,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
```

Make it 0.0